# why this code about matrix multiplication is wrong with outer() command

Tags: r, matrix

```
x <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5), 5, 5)
q <- x %*% t(x)
w <- outer(x, x)
all.equal(q, w)
```

I suppose `outer()` function in R means $x x^{T}$, why `all.equal(q,w)` doesn't give `TRUE`?

Comment: ? what is the difference? outer means $x*x^{T}$

Comment: `outer` of two matrices produces a 4 dimensional array!  Use `tcrossprod` instead of `outer`.

Comment: I didn't get it. why this doesn't work...outer just applies for array? not matrix? According to definition, outer means $xx^{T}$

Comment: @MathildaFang Where did you see this definition ? This is true for a column matrix only, not for a bidimensional matrix.

Comment: thank you for your reply @StéphaneLaurent. I saw from book. Maybe I misunderstood. Could u propose the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding. `outer` applies `FUN` to each **tuple** from `x` and `y`. What your outer call is effectively calculating is (with `` FUN = `*` `` as default):

```
x[1, 1] * x[1, 1]
x[2, 1] * x[1, 1]
...
x[5, 5] * x[5, 5]
```

That is you will end up with `5 x 5 x 5 x 5` elements (i.e. all combinations from `x` and `y`).

As the help files states the resulting array has the dimension `c(dim(x), dim(y))` which is in your case `c(5, 5, 5, 5)`. So `outer` **IS  NOT** equivalent to `x %*% t(y)`

You can see this behaviour with these lines a bit better:

```r
x <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
y <- matrix(LETTERS[1:4], 2, 2)
outer(x, y, FUN = paste0)
# , , 1, 1
#
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "1A" "3A"
# [2,] "2A" "4A"
#
# , , 2, 1
#
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "1B" "3B"
# [2,] "2B" "4B"
# 
# , , 1, 2
#
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "1C" "3C"
# [2,] "2C" "4C"
#
# , , 2, 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "1D" "3D"
# [2,] "2D" "4D"
```

I can only speculate, but I could imagine that the misconception comes from the fact that

```r
i <- 1:4
j <- 1:3
all.equal(outer(i, j), matrix(i, 4, 1) %*% matrix(j, 1, 3))
# [1] TRUE
```

is the same. But then again, what we are calculating is

```
( i[1] * j[1]   i[1] * j[2]   i[1] * j[3] )
( i[2] * j[1]   i[2] * j[2]   i[2] * j[3] )
( i[3] * j[1]   i[3] * j[2]   i[3] * j[3] )
( i[4] * j[1]   i[4] * j[2]   i[4] * j[3] )
```